# php class Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader password protected files read

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using php class Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader , I am confused how to read password protected file through this class  .

I give different permissions to file to read.BUt found no option in excel reader that I can read file through this library

Comment: Note that SEW !== PHPExcel

Comment: I try to give file permissions read only which will work .Initially I works with a file with no permission to view as well without password.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole file is password protected, then you can't: SEW does not read encrypted workbooks. You'll need to use [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) or [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05) or Ilia Alshanetsky's [Excel extension](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel) to the [libXL](http://www.libxl.com/) library to do this (though check before buying libXL, as I'm not certain that it handles password protected files).

Comment: hey I do it in that way , I upload password protected file but with permissions to view and Excel reader reads the file so my work is done